# how to render create page form & list of contents in page.tpl.php

Tags: forms, theming, users

I am theming an admin page & I require to load/render admin forms in page.tpl.php file.
 The final output should be somehow like the attached screenshot. Scroll below to see screenshot & code written in page.tpl.php.

```
<h1 class="page-title">Admin Page</h1>
<div class="content-left">
  <!--load list of all contents("/admin/content") -->
  <?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('node_admin_content')); ?>
</div>
<div class="content-right">
  <!-- add new content form here "/node/add/page") -->
  <?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('page_node_form')); ?>
</div>
```

[image]

I was searching for this solution & I came across this "print drupal_render()". Please suggest best solution for this. I have render same kind of pages in other tpl.php files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to render the forms either in preprocess function or in the custom module. Example of rendering the form in preprocess function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Assigning node_admin_content form to the variable.
  $node_admin_content = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('node_admin_content'));
  $variables['node_admin_content'] = $node_admin_content;

  // Assigning page_node_form form to the variable.
  $page_node_form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('page_node_form'));
  $variables['page_node_form'] = $page_node_form;
}
```

Now to render this form in `page.tpl.php`:

```
<h1 class="page-title">Admin Page</h1>
<div class="content-left">
  <!--load list of all contents("/admin/content") -->
  <?php print $node_admin_content; ?>
</div>
<div class="content-right">
  <!-- add new content form here "/node/add/page") -->
  <?php print $page_node_form; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I'll try this. 
I am not sure if 'node_admin_content' & 'page_node_form' are correct. I took these for respective form id as an example.

Comment: @SureshAlagarYeah I have provided as an example, if you are not sure about the form id than you can `dpm` (if devel module installed) and check it

Comment: Hi Ankit, I found that the id name are correct & I've implemented this preprocess function in template.php file. But I am shown some error message "Notice: Undefined variable: node_admin_content in include()" in page.tpl.php

Comment: @SureshAlagar Have you cleared the cache?, otherwise `$node_admin_content` and `$page_node_form` should provide the result in `page.tpl.php` if the formid's are correct

Comment: @SureshAlagar Can you once check if the error is: `Notice: Undefined index: node_admin_content in drupal_retrieve_form()`, if that is the case than the issue is of the form id

Comment: Hi Ankit, I installed 'Get Form ID' module & found that the id is correct. Please see the screenshot in above screenshot to know error details

Comment: Hi Ankit, please help.

Comment: @SureshAlagar Hi Suresh, once have look at this; http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89406/how-to-get-node-editing-form-in-a-custom-module may be it can be of help to you